# setConnectivityMode Skmaps not working?

Tags: android, skmaps

I 'm trying to make an application that works completely offline. Due to certain resources api skobbler can only be accessed in online mode i have to change to mode offline/online.

In the documentation of the class SKMaps I have seen the following:
[documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/SKMaps.html)

```
public void setConnectivityMode(byte connectivityMode)
   Sets the connectivity mode for the library.
Parameters:
   connectivityMode - can be one of the values CONNECTIVITY_MODE_ONLINE or CONNECTIVITY_MODE_OFFLINE. 
   Before calling this method, make sure that initializeSKMaps(android.content.Context, SKMapsInitSettings, String) is called.
```

I use this method once initialized maps but nothing seems to happen.
Currently I destroy SKmaps and I initialize SKmaps order to change mode.

How should I use this method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you noticed that is not working? Have you seen any files being downloaded? The map is not rendered? If some files are downloaded it will be useful to know which ones? We have to know the exactly problem. Map not being rendered or files being downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

In the current SDK 2.5.1 the methods works correctly.